# Rotate a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list `a` defined,

```
let a = ["#","@","#","#"]
```

How can I rotate the `@` two spaces, so that it ends up like this?

```
["#","#","#","@"]
```

I thought this might work,

```
map last init a
```

but maybe the syntax has to be different, because map can only work with one function?

Comment: This seems underspecified. Do you want cycle behavior so that the other elements wrap around in the list, or do you want nulls or some other sentinel to occupy the places at the beginning of the list that are created by virtue of pushing the elements out the end of the list?

Comment: i want it to look like this ["#","#","#","@"]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For completeness's sake, a version that works with both empty and infinite lists.

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate _ [] = []
rotate n xs = zipWith const (drop n (cycle xs)) xs
```

Then

```
Prelude> rotate 2 [1..5]
[3,4,5,1,2]
```

Comment: The best solution, imho. Very _haskellish_.

Comment: `zipWith const` is genius. I'm stealing that.

Comment: @tel One way of thinking about `zipWith const` is that it's `<*` for [`ZipList`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList).

Comment: gives correct results for rotation amounts down to `0`, for **completeness** see [my bidirectional version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309145/2932052)

Comment: ...or commented different, how would you define "rotation of an infinite list", **isnt' it just** shifting? or **dropping**?

Comment: This solution suffers from large integer input. Try rotate 9999999999 [1, 2, 3] and it takes quite a while to return. Since the function has to process at least `length xs` data points, one should consider calculate the length and drop `mod n (length xs)` instead of drop n elements in the front, which is of O(n) and n can be huge.

Comment: `[ x | x <- drop n (cycle xs) | _ <- xs ]` with the [`-XParallelListComp` extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/parallel_list_comprehensions.html?highlight=parallellistcomp#extension-ParallelListComp)

Answer (score 27):

A simple solution using the `cycle` function, which creates an infinite repetition of the input list:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n xs = take (length xs) (drop n (cycle xs))
```

then

```
> rotate 2 ["#","@","#","#"]
["#","#","#","@"].
```

Comment: Or with less parens, `take (length xs) . drop n . cycle $ xs`

Comment: This solution I found most helpful, though (as the accepted one) it gives correct results for rotation amounts only down to `0`, for completeness see [my bidirectional version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309145/2932052)

Answer (score 20):

Why make it complicated?

```
rotate n xs = bs ++ as where (as, bs) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: However, unlike the other answers this doesn't allow rotating by more than the length of the list.

Answer (score 17):

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate  =  drop <> take
```

Because of the `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` instance the above is equivalent to

```
rotate n  =  drop n <> take n
```

and that is in turn equivalent to

```
rotate n xs  =  drop n xs <> take n xs
```

because of the `instance Monoid d => Monoid (c -> d)` instance, which is equivalent to

```
rotate n xs  =  drop n xs ++ take n xs
```

because of the `instance Monoid [e]` instance (with `b ~ c -> d` and `d ~ [e]`).

(well, `Semigroup` is enough, but that's the same, here).

Comment: Perhaps some explanation is in order? I realize that this implementation is dead simple and pretty clear, but a few actual words would be nice.

Comment: I think this is the most Haskellesque answer in the whole topic and should be the accepted answer. It beautifuly demonstrates a very nice use of `Monoid` instance of `Monoid b => a -> b` type functions by `mappend` or it's infix operator version `<>`. For the `Monoid` instance definition see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-268 Just so cool..

Answer (score 9):

I'm very new to haskell, so the [MGwynne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16378934/2932052) was easy to understand. Combined with the [comment suggesting an alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378773/rotate-a-list-in-haskell#comment23476984_16378934), I tried to make it work in both directions.

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n xs = take lxs . drop (n `mod` lxs) . cycle $ xs where lxs = length xs
```

So `rotate (-1) [1,2,3,4]` gives you the same result as `rotate 3 [1,2,3,4]`.

I thought that I had to add this because `drop`ping less than 0 elements does nothing, so my preferred answer gives "wrong" (at least confusing) results with negative values for the `n` parameter.

The **interesting part** of this solution is that it combines "completeness" for negative rotations with the handling of empty lists. Thanks to Haskell's laziness, it also gives correct results for `rotate 0 []`.

Comment: This should be the best answer, as it does not only handles rotation in opposite direction, it can also handle large n input. The complexity of the algorithm stays at O(list_length) rather than O(n) for large n.

Comment: I upvoted, but: `rotate 1 [1..]` should produce `[2..]`, not get stuck in an infinite loop like it does here with your version. :) OTOH your version is fast with `rotate 100000000` kinds of inputs. if only the two approaches could be combined somehow....

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure if I should add that my solution is only suitable for finite list. Estimates concerning the further generalizability of this solution are unfortunately far beyond my mathematical and Haskell skills.

Answer (score 3):

Beginner attempt:

```
myRotate :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
myRotate 0 xs = xs
myRotate n xs = myRotate (n-1) (last xs : init xs)
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as dblhelix's answer (you are iterating manually instead of using `iterate` and `!!`).

Comment: From a beginner's perspective, it seems much easier to understand. As a beginner, I do not like where clauses because I don't know whether the specified function earlier in the code is a Haskell function or not.  As soon as I read something in the code I don't understand, I stop, and it can be several minutes before I notice there's is a where clause hiding at the bottom that defines the thing that is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Not very fast for large lists, but adequate:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n xs = iterate rot xs !! n
  where
    rot xs = last xs : init xs
```

For example:

```
> rotate 2 ["#","@","#","#"]
["#","#","#","@"]
```

Comment: Thanks man, i'm coming from lisp and im used to all those built in list functions

Comment: @user2002117: We *do* have the `cycle` function built in. It's like a superset of rotate: it gives you a infinite list with every possible rotation in it :P.

Answer (score 0):

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n xs = drop k xs ++ take k xs
                where k = length xs - n
```

This function rotates by n places to the right.