# How to implement rotate function on infinite lists?

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop

I try to implement `rotate` function, which can work with infinite lists. I have problem with `infinite lists`.

My function is:

```
cyclicRotation:: Int -> [a] -> [a]
cyclicRotation num ls = (drop ((length ls) - (mod num (length ls)))  ls) ++ ( take ((length ls) -(mod num (length ls))) ls)
```

I try use my function as:

```
take 2 (cyclicRotation 9 [1..])
```

And I want to get `[10, 11]`.

Comment: `cyclicRotation = drop` ?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: in an infinite list, it makes no difference whether you append the dropped items to the end or not, since you will never reach them later

Comment: I meant that you can just use `drop` as your `cyclicRotation` function

Comment: @mkrieger1, yep, you are right. But how I can determine infinity loops?

Comment: @mkrieger1, no, I don't. There are finite lists.

Comment: hmm you're right, `drop` doesn't rotate *finite* lists...

Comment: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379034/4621513)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would say that question makes this one look like a duplicate... Would you agree David?  If so, I'll close this as a dup.

Comment: Your code would be more readable with less parentheses. And if you use `length ls` not just two but four times (length is inefficient anyway!), it's definitely worth binding that to a local variable. ``cyclicRotation n ls = let l = length ls in drop (l - num`mod`l) ls ++ take (l - num `mod`l) ls``. ...now... what exactly is your question anyway?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, my question is about working with infinity lists. My test is failed.

Comment: @David Using `length` means you can't use infinite lists.  There is no way to detect an infinite list in Haskell, so you should avoid trying to do that and instead work only with the elements you need to pull off the front and stick on the end.  A solution using `Data.List.splitAt` is `rotate n ls = let (first, rest) = splitAt n ls in rest ++ first`.

Comment: Indeed, `length` is the problem. (Again, not _only_ for infinite lists – even for long finite lists it is just slow and often not necessary at all.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yep, as I understand, length has perform O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to work with infinite list you need to avoid non-lazy evaluating functions on it (such as length). Simple example implementation would be:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate _ [] = []
rotate 0 list = list
rotate n (x:xs) = rotate (n-1) (xs ++ [x])
```

Here the `(xs ++ [x])` will work even for infinite lists, since `++` is lazy.