# What is the meaning of `pure x = (\_ -> x)`?

Tags: haskell, types, semantics, typeclass

I'm reading the instance of Applicative for functions,
and encountered a line

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where  
  pure x = (\_ -> x)  
  f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

I understand the syntax, but don't understand the meaning of the second line.

My understanding is: partially applied function `((->) r)` gets a value and wraps that value into the context, which contains function that always returns that value.

Why doesn't it just compute the result by applying partially applied function to that `x`, and only after that it would store the result in Applicative context?

Comment: if it were written `pure x r = x ;  (f <*> g) r = (f r) (g r)` if'd be much clearer, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signatures of `pure` and `(<*>)` for the function instance are

```
pure :: a -> ((->) r a)  
(<*>) :: ((->) r (a -> b)) -> ((->) r a) -> ((->) r b)
```

Writing the (->) as infix operator gives

```
pure :: a -> (r -> a)  
(<*>) :: (r -> (a -> b)) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> a)
```

So `pure` is a function that takes a parameter of type `a` and returns a function that takes a parameter of type `r` and returns a value of type `a`.
Since we can't know the type of `r` as we write `pure`, we can only give a function that return the parameter given to `pure`.

Comment: Could you please provide examples of using pure of function instance?

Comment: @Bulat M. `pure` for the function instance is basically `const`. So you can use it in the same places (like you can use `pure` instead of `Just`, or `(:[])`. Using `pure` instead of those allows you to potentially make more general code(one that works for any applicative, rather than a particular instance).

Comment: Please elaborate more on one concrete example where it allows to make more general code. It would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: for example, consider `liftA2 f a b = pure f <*> a <*> b`, which can be used like on functions like so `liftA2 (+) (*3) (/6)` which would give the function equivalent to `\x -> (x*3) + (x/6)`, thus we can apply the same argument to multiple functions, then combine the results some in way. Another example of using liftA2 `liftA2 (,) (^2) show`, which will take a number a create a tuple with its square and its string representation. For usecases of `const` you can check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402528/whats-the-point-of-const-in-the-haskell-prelude)